# Apparent size of M31

Tags: amateur-observing

I am trying to understand something I read on wikipedia about M31.

Wikipedia says that M31 appears more than six times as wide as the full Moon.

But I remember that when I watched it naked eye it seamed a lot smaller, even considering that I was able to see only the central region. For this reason I also used the software Stellarium to check it and setting the same magnification for the two objects (see pictures), the wikipedia information still seems wrong ... or most likely I am wrong!

Where is that I fail?

"At an apparent magnitude of 3.4, the Andromeda Galaxy is one of the brightest Messier objects,[15] making it visible to the naked eye on moonless nights even when viewed from areas with moderate light pollution. Although **it appears more than six times as wide as the full Moon** when photographed through a larger telescope, only the brighter central region is visible to the naked eye or when viewed using binoculars or a small telescope"

[image: M31]

[image: Moon]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is right there in your screenshots. The 'dimensione' or angular diameter on the sky is 3 degrees for M31, whereas the moon has an angular diameter of only 0.5 degrees. In other words, M31 is about 6 times as wide as the moon.

As wikipedia correctly states, you need a large telescope to see the full extend of M31. With the naked eye of even a small telescope you simply cannot see the spiral arms.

I think this image shows it very neatly:
http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/ap061228.html